# Sublime text3 jsp page toggle comment

Tags: jsp, comments, sublimetext3

Hi guys I work in jsp pages a lot and wanted to customize my jsp custom extensions in ST3.

currently in ST3 if i'm in jsp the toggle comment gives me basic html

is there a way to edit my pref to;